app-buddle.js.map is not getting generated when running npm run build in aurelia framework
I updated the bootstrap version and also updated sourceMap and after that if i run the npm run build dist folder and app-bundle.js.map is not getting generated.
node version is 20.14.0
npm version is 10.9.0
aurelia version is 3.0.3
Please let me know what is the reason.
